# Call to a member function diff() on string on laravel

Tags: laravel

On my Controller I have the code:

```
public function receita(Request $request){
    $id = $request['id'];
    $marcacao = Marcacao::find($id);

    $produtos = ProdutoUnidade::where('unidade_id', $marcacao->agenda->vinculo->unidade->id)
                              ->get();

    $vencimento = new DateTime(date("y-m-d"));
    $vencimento->add(new DateInterval('P90D'));
    $vencimento = $vencimento->format('y-m-d');

    return view('agendas.receita', compact('marcacao', 'produtos', 'vencimento'));
}
```

In my blade, I have:

```
@foreach($produtos as $produto)
    <option value="{{$produto->id}}">
        {{$vencimento->diff($produto->produtoNota->dataValidade) > 60 ? '0' : '1'}}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

I want to know if the difference of $vencimento and $produto->produtoNota->dataValidade is bigger than 60, but I am receive the error:

> Call to a member function diff() on string

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you cast DateTime to string with `$vencimento = $vencimento->format('y-m-d');` then pass this variable to the view.

So you are calling `->diff` on a string. Pass DateTime object to view and format it there if you need to output formated datetime.

P.S. I suggest using carbon instead.

Comment: I comment the line `$vencimento = $vencimento->format('y-m-d');` and generate other error: `DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given`

Comment: How to use carbon?

Comment: I assume you do not cast dates from database to carbon object. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators